How do I find all combinations of pairs, such that no elements of the combination have a common first or last value?
I have a list of number-letter pairs like:
all_edges_array = [
                   [1,'a'],[1,'b'],[1,'c'],
                   [2,'c'],[2,'d'],
                   [3,'b'],[3,'c']
                  ]

Notice that the input pairs are not a cross-product of the letters and numbers used - for example, [2, 'a'] is missing.
I want to efficiently find the combinations of some number of pairs, such that within a group, no two pairs use the same number or the same letter.
For the above input, there should be 5 total results: [([1, 'a'], [2, 'c'], [3, 'b']), ([1, 'a'], [2, 'd'], [3, 'b']), ([1, 'a'], [2, 'd'], [3, 'c']), ([1, 'b'], [2, 'd'], [3, 'c']), ([1, 'c'], [2, 'd'], [3, 'b'])].
Other combinations are not valid: for example, ([1, 'a'], [1, 'b'], [3, 'c']) contains two pairs using the same number (1), and ([1, 'b'], [2, 'c'], [3, 'b']) contains two pairs using the same letter (b).
I have code which brute-forces this by using itertools.combinations and then filtering the result:
from itertools import combinations

number_letter_dict = {1:['a','b','c'], 2:['c','d'], 3:['b','c']}

# create the edges based on the connections in the number_letter_dict
all_edges_array = []
for key in number_letter_dict.keys():
    for item in number_letter_dict[key]:
        all_edges_array.append([key, item])

# get the number of connections relative to the number of keys in dict
number_of_connections = len(number_letter_dict.keys())

# Find all 35 combinations
all_combinations_array = list(combinations(all_edges_array, number_of_connections))

# cut down the list of combinations to what I actually need
all_good_combinations = []
for collection in all_combinations_array:
    duplicated_item = False
    seen_indices = []
    for item in collection:
        if item[0] in seen_indices:
            duplicated_item = True
            break
        if item[1] in seen_indices:
            duplicated_item = True
            break
        seen_indices.append(item[0])
        seen_indices.append(item[1])
    # all clear--add the collection! :)
    if not duplicated_item:
        all_good_combinations.append(collection)

This works, but it's inefficient - it takes an unacceptably long time to run for my actual input. Many more combinations are generated than are valid, which only gets worse the more edges and connections there are.
How can I improve on this algorithm? I assume that it involves not generating invalid combinations in the first place, but I don't see a way to accomplish that.
I found the previous Q&A Python: How to generate all combinations of lists of tuples without repeating contents of the tuple, but it doesn't answer my question. The answers there assume that the input contains all possible pairs (and also that the number of pairs in the combinations should be equal to the number of possibilities for the more constrained pair element).
EDIT: I have replaced some of the minimized code because it caused more confusion than it saved: oops? Also, this code does work. When given enough time it will reliably give the correct answer. That said, spending five days processing one image is not quite fast enough for my tastes.

I've adited per the discussion we had in the Staging Ground. It changes more than I originally imagined, but I think I've captured the problem much more clearly now. Please carefully note how I avoid repetition and irrelevant information (in particular: you don't need to tell us that your code example is cut down to make a proper [mre], because we expect you to do that anyway). Just to make sure: the number of pairs you want in the output combinations is arbitrary, yes? It's not necessarily equal to the number of distinct letters, nor numbers, used in the input?

Is number_of_connections always 3, or why is that hard-wired into the lengthy comparison code lines?

I also updated the title to describe the problem more clearly. While it's possible to contemplate this problem with longer sub-elements in the input (all the same length, of course), it becomes much harder to describe that problem within the title character limit. (Also, saying "pairs" is clearer because you didn't actually use tuples for the sub-elements in the example ;) )

@nocomment because there are only three distinct numbers used for the first value in each pair, number_of_connections would be at most 3, or else we cna trivially conclude that there are no solutions. But as I understood it, OP does also want to consider cases where number_of_connections differs.

Would help a lot to know what your actual input is like.

@KarlKnechtel But about their code they said "This works, but it's inefficient - it takes an unacceptably long time to run for my actual input". So either that's not true, i.e., that code doesn't work for their actual input, or their actual input only wants triples (since that's what those lines check).

@KarlKnechtel The number of pairs in the output combinations is relative to the number of numbers--I create my all_edges_array by double for-looping through a dictionary using its keys. The number of connections I need to have, then, would be based on the number of numbers. An example of this I've included below:
num_letter_dict = {}
num_letter_dict[1] = ['a','b','c']
num_letter_dict[2] = ['c','d']
num_letter_dict[3] = ['b','c']

all_edges_array = []
for key in num_letter_dict.keys():
    for item in num_letter_dict[key]:
        all_edges_array.append([key, item])


@nocomment Sorry for the confusion--I have edited my question to remove the source of the issue. I had figured that my 'cutting down' code wouldn't be necessary because this was a toy problem I was trying to use to get algorithm help, but I don't think that's quite what occurred. Please have a look at the new code!

What if the source data looked like this: [[1,'a'],[2,'b'],[3,'a']], would you say there is no valid result, or would you say [[1,'a'],[2,'b']] and [[2,'b'],[3,'a']] are still valid results, even though they don't include all integer values? That is, does any subset that can't be extended with another value from the original collection count as a valid result?

@Grismar Your example would result in no valid result with my current way of approaching the problem. If I were to add in the ability to have more subsets that would slow down my processing speed significantly, unfortunately.

Since when should the speed of computation affect the desired outcome? I agree with you that getting a result would be slower, but "I wrote you a program that does Y because a program that would do X would be too slow" is rarely an acceptable outcome if someone needs a program that does X. What do you need this for?

I reworked the question on Codidact according to my understanding of it - because I no longer write new answers for Stack Overflow - and wrote two answers giving possible approaches. You may find it useful: https://software.codidact.com/posts/292957 I use the same Creative Commons license there, so everyone is welcome to cite and adapt those answers here.

@Grismar When dealing with applied programming, the speed very much effects the acceptablility of the program. In my case, when processing many many images, if I am required to spend four days minimum processing a single image it would be better to just cut out this part of the program and redesign how it works. That said, I would really like to not do that.

@KarlKnechtel Thank you so much! I really appreciate your help.

It is always inefficient to generate all combinations and throw away unwanted combinations when you can selectively generate wanted combinations to begin with.
The desired combinations can be most efficiently generated by recursively yielding combinations of unused letters paired with the number of the current recursion level, where a set can be used to keep track used letters:
def unique_combinations(number_letter_dict):
    def _unique_combinations(index):
        if index == size:
            yield ()
            return
        number, letters = number_letters[index]
        for letter in letters:
            if letter not in used_letters:
                used_letters.add(letter)
                for combination in _unique_combinations(index + 1):
                    yield [number, letter], *combination
                used_letters.remove(letter)
    number_letters = list(number_letter_dict.items())
    size = len(number_letters)
    used_letters = set()
    return list(_unique_combinations(0))

so that:
number_letter_dict = {1: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 2: ['c', 'd'], 3: ['b', 'c']}
print(unique_combinations(number_letter_dict))

outputs:
[([1, 'a'], [2, 'c'], [3, 'b']), ([1, 'a'], [2, 'd'], [3, 'b']), ([1, 'a'], [2, 'd'], [3, 'c']), ([1, 'b'], [2, 'd'], [3, 'c']), ([1, 'c'], [2, 'd'], [3, 'b'])]

Demo: https://ideone.com/FfZwod

I tried this with number_letter_dict = dict.fromkeys(range(1, 12), list('abcdefghij')). Took 13 seconds to find the 0 combinations. You still generate and throw away many (partial) combinations. Can we do better?

I don't see how my code is throwing away any combination unless you're calling the call stack itself a partial combination, which is simply a necessity in search of viable paths.

I just tried number_letter_dict = dict.fromkeys(range(1, 9), list('abcdefghij')). Took 3.4 seconds with my code on my machine, and with your code, 25.3 seconds. With range(1, 12) your code wouldn't finish before I ran out of patience.

@nocomment FWIW I've come up with a near-instant solution for your very input, while still performant for other typical inputs: https://onlinegdb.com/Mny2LzQKpg

Yes, the call stack's number and letter values is what I meant. I had considered a few ways to stop futile recursion paths early or other things, but without knowing what their  actual input is like, I didn't want to potentially waste the effort. One idea was a form of memoization. For my example, you enter your helper function with at most 2^10 different states (your index is no further factor, as it is redundant, it equals len(used_letters)). That would be very quick, too.

Here's one such "memoized" version. I kept your solution as-is, only added six lines related to stop.

This solution worked perfectly for me! I just copied it into my program and it now works--thank you so much, @blhsing!

You throw away and ignore the structure you already had, in your dict. We can instead use the product of its values, which avoids pointless generation and filtering of combinations with equal numbers. Just still needs checking the letters.
from itertools import product

number_letter_dict = {1:['a','b','c'], 2:['c','d'], 3:['b','c']}

all_good_combinations = [
    list(zip(number_letter_dict, letters))
    for letters in product(*number_letter_dict.values())
    if len(set(letters)) == len(number_letter_dict)
]

for c in all_good_combinations:
    print(c)

Output (Attempt This Online!):
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'b')]
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'd'), (3, 'b')]
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'd'), (3, 'c')]
[(1, 'b'), (2, 'd'), (3, 'c')]
[(1, 'c'), (2, 'd'), (3, 'b')]


This is the right answer, although it does not avoid checking many duplicate solutions, which seems to be at the core of OP's question (even if I doubt the need for speed is so dire that this solution would not work)

@Grismar What duplicate solutions do you mean?

I believe Grismar is referring to the filtering implemented by if len(set(letters)) == len(number_letter_dict). The Cartesian product here generates 12 candidates and over half of them are rejected. For a larger input this could become much more noticeable. However, solutions that attempt preemptive filtering  will lose the advantage that itertools offers by implementing the hard parts in C, and may also fail to take advantage of the structure in the data that you mention.

@KarlKnechtel Yeah, I guess so, but I wouldn't call that "duplicate solutions". Yes, for the OP's example this only checks 12 candidates instead of their 35, and ends up with only 5. Both ratios (35/12 and 12/5) probably increase with larger data, but that depends on their data. So it could be fast enough or could still be too slow. I see it as a faster and very simple solution. If it's still too slow, it can still be useful for testing other solutions with medium size data. I commented that it would help a lot to know what their actual input is like, but they didn't react to that.

You're right that it's probably inefficient your way. I'm not sure you actual input, but the number of initial solutions (valid or invalid) will grow substantially if the length grows. Instead you can approach this via recursion/backtracking. I generally hate backtracking, but this seems like a good use case.
Basically start by forming a map from int -> str to know source -> dest node. This can be done like so:
for number, letter in all_edges_array:
    number_to_letters[number].append(letter)

So now if we want to know what 1 attaches to, we can do this:
>>> number_to_letters[1]
['a', 'b', 'c']

Next is the actual algorithm. Basically go through until you reach length N, in this case 3. Once you've reached it add a copy of whatever that list is and  return.
If you're still building the list then look at the next valid source node. Remember, we've essentially created islands for the source nodes within the mapping. Then we check the edges that connect from the next source, and if that destination isn't in a set of our "used" ones, then we can add it. Then we just recurse + backtrack.
That can be done below:
sources = list(number_to_letters.keys())

def find_combinations(current_combination, used_letters, results):
    # If we've reached the target length, add to results
    if len(current_combination) == number_of_connections:
        results.append(current_combination[:])
        return

    # Find the next number to add a pair for
    # NOTE below
    next_idx = len(current_combination)
    if next_idx >= len(sources):
        return
    next_number = sources[next_idx]

    # Try each letter for the current number and make sure it's not used
    for letter in number_to_letters[next_number]:
        if letter not in used_letters:
            # Add the pair and recurse
            current_combination.append((next_number, letter))
            used_letters.add(letter)
            find_combinations(current_combination, used_letters, results)
            # Backtrack
            current_combination.pop()
            used_letters.remove(letter)

and running it:
>>> find_combinations([], set(), results)
>>> results
[[(1, 'a'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'b')],
 [(1, 'a'), (2, 'd'), (3, 'b')],
 [(1, 'a'), (2, 'd'), (3, 'c')],
 [(1, 'b'), (2, 'd'), (3, 'c')],
 [(1, 'c'), (2, 'd'), (3, 'b')]]

Now for the NOTE above. Depending how your sources are laid out, you could potentially just look at the next number. So if your sources are all numerically increasing by 1, then you could just add +1 and not have to list the sources.

You could use their number_letter_dict now.

If you want combinations of length comb_length, they have to contain exactly comb_length different numbers.
We first generate all possible combinations of this many numbers (in all_combinations).
Then, for each of these combinations of numbers, we generate recursively the possible combinations (in edge_combinations), keeping track of the letters we used and the index of the current number. Using a generator, we can yield the combinations one by one, building them in reverse when we have remaining letters for the last number.
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import combinations


def edge_combinations(letters_for_nums, nums, max_num_idx, used_letters=set(), curr_idx=0):
    available_letters = letters_for_nums[nums[curr_idx]] - used_letters
    
    # If there are no available letters left, we abandon this path immediately
    if not available_letters:
        return

    num = nums[curr_idx]

    if curr_idx==max_num_idx:
        # We have available letters for the last number, we start yielding from the end
        for letter in available_letters:
            yield [[num, letter]]
    else: 
        for letter in available_letters:
            for subcomb in edge_combinations(letters_for_nums, nums, max_num_idx,
                                             used_letters=used_letters | {letter},
                                             curr_idx = curr_idx+1):
                yield [[num, letter]] + subcomb


def all_combinations(edges, comb_length):
    # We build a dict {number: set of corresponding letters}
    letters_for_nums = defaultdict(set)
    for num, letter in edges:
        letters_for_nums[num].add(letter)
    
    # And make a list of numbers:
    all_nums = [num for num in letters_for_nums]

    # We try all combinations of comb_length of these numbers
    for nums in combinations(all_nums, r=comb_length):
        yield from edge_combinations(letters_for_nums, nums, max_num_idx=comb_length-1)

Sample run
edges = [[1,'a'],[1,'b'],[1,'c'],
         [2,'c'],[2,'d'],
         [3,'b'],[3,'c']
        ]

for c in all_combinations(edges, 3):
    print(c)

Output
[[1, 'a'], [2, 'c'], [3, 'b']]
[[1, 'a'], [2, 'd'], [3, 'b']]
[[1, 'a'], [2, 'd'], [3, 'c']]
[[1, 'b'], [2, 'd'], [3, 'c']]
[[1, 'c'], [2, 'd'], [3, 'b']]

With combinations of length 2, we would get:
[[1, 'a'], [2, 'c']]
[[1, 'a'], [2, 'd']]
[[1, 'b'], [2, 'c']]
[[1, 'b'], [2, 'd']]
[[1, 'c'], [2, 'd']]
[[1, 'a'], [3, 'b']]
[[1, 'a'], [3, 'c']]
[[1, 'b'], [3, 'c']]
[[1, 'c'], [3, 'b']]
[[2, 'c'], [3, 'b']]
[[2, 'd'], [3, 'b']]
[[2, 'd'], [3, 'c']]


"We first generate all possible combinations of this many numbers" - There's exactly one, I think. Note their number_of_connections = len(number_letter_dict.keys()).

Also note that you're rebuilding their number_letter_dict.

You can treat this as more of a graph problem than a combinatorics problem. Your all_edges example would be the graph where nodes that are adjacent share either a letter or a number:
      3b
     /  \
   1b    3c
  /  \  /  \
1a -- 1c -- 2c -- 2d

The graph helps identify partitions of the original graph where numbers and letters aren't shared between partitions because once you've selected a node, all its neighbors are no longer eligible.
One possible partitioning method is finding all trees with height 5. Then for each tree, the 1st, 3rd, and 5th levels constitute a valid partition b/c the 2nd and 4th levels separate them.
For each partition, call itertools.product() to generate all solutions. There may be some duplicates, but shouldn't be very many.

def find unique combinations(pairs):
    # Helper function to check if a combination is valid
    def is_valid_combination(combo):
        first_elements = set()
        last_elements = set()
        for pair in combo:
            if pair[0] in first_elements or pair[1] in last_elements:
                return False
            first_elements.add(pair[0])
            last_elements.add(pair[1])
        return True

    # Recursive function to generate combinations
    def generate_combinations(index, current_combo):
        # If the current combination is valid, store it
        if is_valid_combination(current_combo):
            results.append(list(current_combo))

        # Iterate over remaining pairs to form new combinations
        for i in range(index, len(pairs)):
            current_combo.append(pairs[i])
            generate_combinations(i + 1, current_combo)
            current_combo.pop()

    results = []
   


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
